# RTRIM only the last 3 digits

Tags: oracle, function, oracle10g

I have a figure to and i want to trim the last 3 digits which are always zeros,but for this one i have four zeros and if i use the rtrim to remove the zeros it removes four of them.Below is and example

rtrim(15,250,000,"0")

what i want is to remove only the last three zeros

thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's always a number how about keeping it as a number instead of a character string and simply dividing by 1000?

Answer (score 3):

If they are *always* zeroes, how about simply keeping the substring that starts at the beginning of the string and extends to the length of the string minus three characters?

Comment: that sounds cool but how can i minus three characters from it ?

Comment: @bsanneh SUBSTRING(string_column_name, 1, LENGTH(string_column_name) - 3)